# Installing a CPU-based library version on a GPU enabled machine

Tags: pytorch

I want to install a CPU version of [PyTorch](http://pytorch.org/) on a server which is equipped with a nVIDIA Tesla GPU. Will it work or can I only install a GPU version (with CUDA) on this server for PyTorch to function properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of PyTorch with GPU support also works with CPU (but the cpu training of neural networks is really slow). So you can install the GPU version. Make sure you install PyTorch compiled with the correct cuda version (cuda 7.5, cuda 8.0 or cuda 9.0).